# $\overline{A}\cap B\neq\emptyset$ or $\overline{B}\cap A\neq\emptyset$ implies $\operatorname{dist}(A,B)=0$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$\overline{A}\cap B\neq\emptyset$ or $\overline{B}\cap A\neq\emptyset$ implies $\operatorname{dist}(A,B)=0$. I have tried to prove this but was unable to find a decent method. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: A LaTeX tip: the symbol for "empty set" should either be `\emptyset` ($\emptyset$) or `\varnothing` ($\varnothing$). It is a distinct symbol from the Greek letter phi (`\phi` in LaTeX, making $\phi$).

Comment: Rather than simply saying that you could not prove a statement, tell us what you tried to do to prove it. Also, you should provide more context in your questions, including what class you encountered them in and what textbook(s) you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Prove the contrapositive: if $\operatorname{dist}(A,B)>0$, then $(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap B=\varnothing=A\cap\operatorname{cl}B$.

Comment: I shall try the contrapositive thanks for the tip

Comment: @Rajinda: You’re welcome.

Comment: Let x∊A and y∊B and dist(A,B)>0. Then ρ(x,y)>0 x∊A and y∊B. Then ρ(x,y)>0 and $x∊\overline{A}$ and y∊Bwhich implies $\overline{A}∩B=∅$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: @Rajinda: You have the right idea, but it could be said much better. Let $r=\operatorname{dist}(A,B)$, and let $x\in A$. Then $d(x,y)\ge r$ for all $y\in B$, so $B_d(x,r)\cap B=\varnothing$, where $B_d(x,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$. This shows that $x\notin\operatorname{cl}B$ and hence that $A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Rajinda: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see how to prove either of these two facts?

- $\mathrm{dist}(A,B) = \mathrm{dist}(A,\overline B)$
- If $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$, then $\mathrm{dist}(A,B) = 0$.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Yes I can prove the two statements but need help to relate it to my question

Comment: OK let's suppose $A \cap \overline B \neq \varnothing$. Can you then re-write $\mathrm{dist}( A , \overline B)$ in two different ways? (using the above two bullet points).

Comment: Then $dist(\overline{B}\cap A)=0$ right? and dist($\overline{A}\cap B)=dist(A,B)$

Comment: I think you have some typos in your last comment. What does $\mathrm{dist}(X)$ mean when $X$ is set?

Comment: The infimum of ρ(x,y)s for each x,y in X

Comment: It's true that one usually defines $\mathrm{dist}(X,Y) = \inf_{x \in X, y \in Y} \rho(x,y)$ when $X,Y$ are two sets. If you define $\mathrm{dist}(X) = \inf_{x,y \in X} \rho(x,y)$ then you always get $0$ (at least if $X \neq \varnothing$) since in the infimum I can always take $x, y$ to both to be some point $z \in X$ and then $\rho(x,y) = \rho(z,z) = 0$ meaning $\mathrm{dist}(X) = 0$ as you are proposing to define it. Roughly, the distance from a set to a self is zero, as you might expect. So, people would not use this definition.

Answer (score 1):

Assume WLOG that $\overline{A} \cap B \ne \emptyset$. If $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon(x)$ contains at least one point of $A$, so $\operatorname{diet}(A, B) < \epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof.